# Jmeter scenario design

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I have a file "District.csv" which has "10 agents"
I want to create 110 subagents under all these "10 agents" as 11 subagents for each agent and write out to a file

like

Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent1
Agent2,subagent2
Agent2,subagent2
Agent2,subagent2
Agent2,subagent2
Agent2,subagent2
Agent2,subagent2
Agent2,subagent2
Agent2,subagent2
.
.
.
So on

can someone please help me to achieve it. please help me with JMX for this scenario if possible

Thanks in advance

I tried

Thread group - 10 thread
loop controller - 11
Sampler - to create the agents
``post processor - to write out to a file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file with 10 agents which looks like:

```
Agent1
Agent2
Agent3
...
Agent10
```

and would like to modify it to look like:

```
Agent1,subagent1
Agent1,subagent2
...
Agent1,subagent11
Agent2,subagent1
...
Agent10,subagent11
```

You can:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) to your test
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def builder = new StringBuilder()

   def csvFile = new File('test.csv')

   def lines = csvFile.readLines()

   lines.each { line ->
       1.upto(11, {
           builder.append(line).append(',').append('subagent').append(it).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
       })
   }

   csvFile.text = builder.toString()
   ```

   the above code will replace the contents of your original CSV file with "subagents" added, you will be able to use it with i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in the "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)